# Error on Edit and Create: uncaught at handleFetch addRecords/newRecordsById

Tags: javascript, admin-on-rest

I'm using **admin-on-rest**.

When I press the `EditButton` in the List (no matter for what resource) I immediatly get the following error in the Firefox console:

> uncaught at handleFetch
>   addRecords/newRecordsById<@http://wzm-api.lcl:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45129:10

If i press the `SaveButton` the spinning indicator never ends.

But the record is saved nevertheless.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Hard to debug from a bundled file... Can you trace the error to one of the admin-on-rest files (using sourcemaps)?